# Можно ли так обращаться к форме из потока? Delphi

Tags: delphi, многопоточность

В процедуре

```
procedure TTreads.Execute;
begin
  if Form1.CheckBox1.Checked then
  begin
    ......
  end;
end;
```

Можно ли обращаться к `CheckBox1` из потока? Или нужно синхронизировать и передавать значение через boolean?

Comment: В данном конкретном случае - да, можно. Потому что свойство Checked для возврата значения использует только внутреннее поле FState простого типа, соответственно - обращение к нему будет потокобезопасно. А вот установка этого свойства уже не потокобезопасна.

Comment: Ага, я так и предполагал, это значит я так же могу читать значение из edit.text и memo.text, читать можно, редактировать нельзя.

Comment: К VCL из потоков обращаться нельзя.

Comment: `это значит я так же могу читать значение из edit.text и memo.text`. Нет, читать возможно только простые типы данных. И то - только если они не приводят к взаимодействию с ОС, а хранятся в виде таких же простых полей внутри объекта, к которому идет обращение. Я не зря начал свой предыдущий комментарий с фразы "В данном конкретном случае".

Comment: Понял, текст нельзя читать, а делать так можно? `if form1.checkBox1.Checked then` или вот так `if form1.ComboBox1.ItemIndex = 1 then`, спасибо

Comment: Каждый случай из разряда "можно - не можно" следует рассматривать отдельно, анализируя исходный код VCL, что может быть не очень просто. Гораздо легче считать, что всё обращение к VCL должно идти через Synchronize или (в последних версиях Delphi) Queue. Благо они имеют возможность использования анонимных методов.

Answer (score 3):

Можно, но это очень неправильно и только вопрос времени когда у тебя будет Access Violation.

Можно ли вместо педалей в велосипеде использовать костыли? Можно, но это очень неправильно.

Вся работа должна осуществляться 
1) через synchronize
2) убрать прямую зависимость на основную форму - используй интерфейс.

Пример использования synchronize из потока:

```
 if RMain <> nil then
   Synchronize(
     procedure
     begin
       RMain.UpdateImage(FBitmap);
     end
   );
```

`RMain` это какой-то интерфейс. например: `IViewControl`
реализован он в какой-то форме, например `Form1`

```
type
  TTaskImage = class(TThread)
  protected
    FBitmap: TBitMap;
    FFileName: String;

    class var
      RMain: IViewControl;

    procedure Execute; override;
    procedure ThreadCompleted(Sender: TObject);
  public
    constructor Create(AFileName: String);
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

constructor TTaskImage.Create(AFileName: String);
begin
  if RMain = nil then
    FormHelper.GetFirstForm(IViewControl, RMain);

  OnTerminate := ThreadCompleted;

  FFileName := AFileName;

  inherited Create(True);
end;
```

в основном потоке:

```
  TfmMain = class(TForm, IViewControl)
```

чтобы не допустить ситуации, когда пытаются закрыть основую форму, пока порождённые ей потоки всё ещё работают следующее:
1) пытаемся остановить все потоки
2) если хоть один поток ещё работает, запрещаем выход, но ставим флаг отложенной операции по закрытию.

```
procedure TfmMain.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  TaskImages.StopTasks;

  with CriticalSection do
    if FImagesThreadPool.LockList.Count > 0 then
      begin
        Action := caNone;
        EnterCriticalSection(Section);
        try
          FPostponedCloseOnceAllTaskCompleted := True;
        finally
          LeaveCriticalSection(Section);
        end;
      end;
end;

procedure TfmMain.ImageThreadComleted(const AThread: TThread);

  function FormatProgressLabel(AValue: Integer): String;
  begin
    Result := Format('There are %d images loaded', [AValue]);
  end;

var
  LFileName: String;
  LIndex: Integer;
  LActionRequired: Boolean;
  LPostponedCloseOnceAllTaskCompleted: Boolean;
  LThreadsCompleted: Integer;
begin
  { Remove thread from pool list }
  LIndex := CriticalSection.FImagesThreadPool.LockList.IndexOf(AThread);

  if LIndex = -1 then
    Exit;

  CriticalSection.FImagesThreadPool.LockList.Remove(
    CriticalSection.FImagesThreadPool.LockList.Items[LIndex]);

  if CriticalSection.FImagesThreadPool.LockList.Count = 0 then
    EnDsControls(True);

  EnterCriticalSection(CriticalSection.Section);
  try
    LPostponedCloseOnceAllTaskCompleted :=
      CriticalSection.FPostponedCloseOnceAllTaskCompleted;
  finally
    LeaveCriticalSection(CriticalSection.Section);
  end;

  if LPostponedCloseOnceAllTaskCompleted then
    Close;

  { Should we run next thread? }
  EnterCriticalSection(CriticalSection.Section);
  try
    LActionRequired :=
      (CriticalSection.FImagesThreadPool.LockList.Count < CONST_MAX_THREADS)
      and (CriticalSection.FPendingFiles.Count > 0);
    Inc(CriticalSection.FThreadsCompleted);
    LThreadsCompleted := CriticalSection.FThreadsCompleted;
  finally
    LeaveCriticalSection(CriticalSection.Section);
  end;

  { GUI }
  lblThreadsCompleted.Caption := FormatProgressLabel(LThreadsCompleted);

  if not LActionRequired then
    Exit;

  with CriticalSection do
    begin
      EnterCriticalSection(CriticalSection.Section);
      try
        LFileName := FPendingFiles[FPendingFiles.Count - 1];
        FPendingFiles.Delete(FPendingFiles.Count - 1);
      finally
        LeaveCriticalSection(Section);
      end;
    end;

  { Run next thread }
  TaskImages.RunImageViewThread(LFileName, tpLowest);
end;
```

полный исходный код данного проекта доступен на:
https://github.com/KohrAhr/MultithreadedImageThumbnailViewer

использован Delphi DX10 Seattle. (без Update 1) (без зависимостей от 3-х компонентов).

Comment: Между проверкой на nil и вызовом синхронизации, переменная может успеть стать nil. Вероятно проверку стоит ввести внутрь синхронизации?

Comment: нет. данная переменная не сможет. 
RMain не принадлежит основному потоку.

  `TTaskImage = class(TThread)
  protected
    class var
      RMain: IViewControl;`

Comment: `constructor TTaskImage.Create(AFileName: String);
begin
  if RMain = nil then
    FormHelper.GetFirstForm(IViewControl, RMain);`

Comment: Добавите это в ответ?

Comment: @Kromster -- done

Comment: Какой-то оверкилл получился, если честно. P.S. `with CriticalSection do begin EnterCriticalSection(CriticalSection.Section);` - with Шредингера, он тут как бы и есть, и как бы его нет.

Comment: возможно. данный проект - тестовое задание от AusLogics, которое необходимо было выполнить за выходные. возможно некоторые косметические моменты я упустил.

Comment: @Kromster -- лучше скачай весь проект и сделай ему Code Review. спасибо.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58492/discussion-between-kromster-and-zam).

Answer (score 1):

> Можно ли так обращаться к форме из потока?

Нет, лучше так не делать. Иногда это прокатит (чтение простых типов), но лучше взять за правило, все обращения к VCL делать через `Synchronize`. *Синтаксис расписывать не буду, он вам по-видимому знаком.*

Есть присказка на тему:

> В (многопоточном) программировании, если вероятность какого-то события равна 1 из миллиона, то оно случится в продакшене примерно в следующий вторник.

Answer (score 0):

Если просто читаешь данные с формы (а не записываешь их) и форма создается перед запуском потока и уничтожается после завершения потока, то можно не бояться.